# SVG - animate scale element from origin

Tags: react-native, svg

I'm trying to create a pulsating effect of an svg icon in React-Native (react-native-svg). I'm fine with the animating aspect of it using Reanimated. I'm thinking of creating a pulsating effect by changing the 'scale' value of the Path. The problem is that modifying the 'scale' value either 'cuts off' the visible part of the image if the scale value is > 1 or with values less than 1, it zooms out moving to the side (ie. not remaining in the centre of view. I understand that svg treats the top left corner as the origin.

```
const AnimatedPath = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Path);

const PulsatingSign = () => {
  return (
    <Svg width={43} height={63} viewBox="0 0 43 63" fill="red">
      <AnimatedPath scale={animatedValue} d="M......" />
    </Svg>
  );
};
```

Only thing I can think of is to animate (ie: change values of) the `width` and `height`:

```
const PulsatingSign = () => {
  return (
    <Svg width={animatedWidth} height={animatedHeight} viewBox={`0 0 ${animatedWidth} ${animatedHeight}`} fill="red">
      <Path d="M......" />
    </Svg>
  );
};
```

Or wrap the svg component with View and scale the View (My assumption is that it'd be more performant to animate the svg element directly, not the wrapping view, though.

```
const PulsatingSign = () => {
  return (
    <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ scale: animatedValue }]}>
      <Svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 43 67" fill="red">
        <Path d="M......" />
      </Svg>
    </Animated.View>
  );
};
```

What would be the best way of keeping the icon right in the middle and keep pulsating it (ie. rescaling it).

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. The 0,0-point of the path is somewhere -- not in the middle -- from the path.
2. Scaling makes the path bigger tan the viewBox.

Without changing the path (you could also change the path by moving the 0,0-point to the middle of the path) you can animate e parent group element instead and at the same tine transform/translate the path so that the 0,0-point ends up in the middle of the path.

Instead of scaling the path up, so that it becomes too big for the viewBox you could scale the path down. Alternative is to either make the viewBox larger or edit the path so that it becomes smaller.

```css
svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>Plain SVG path</p>
<svg width="43" height="63" viewBox="0 0 43 63" fill="red">
  <path d="M 2 2 L 21 5 L 41 2 L 36 29 L 41 60 L 21 55 L 2 60 L 7 29 Z" />
</svg>

<p>Issue: scales from 0,0 and is too big</p>
<svg width="43" height="63" viewBox="0 0 43 63" fill="red">
  <path d="M 2 2 L 21 5 L 41 2 L 36 29 L 41 60 L 21 55 L 2 60 L 7 29 Z">
    <animateTransform
      attributeName="transform"
      attributeType="XML"
      type="scale"
      values="1; 1.5; 1"
      dur="2s"
      repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
</svg>

<p>Issue: is too big</p>
<svg width="43" height="63" viewBox="0 0 43 63" fill="red">
  <g transform="translate(22 30)">
    <g>
      <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        attributeType="XML"
        type="scale"
        values="1; 1.5; 1"
        dur="2s"
        repeatCount="indefinite" />
      <path transform="translate(-22 -30)"
        d="M 2 2 L 21 5 L 41 2 L 36 29 L 41 60 L 21 55 L 2 60 L 7 29 Z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>

<p>No issues</p>
<svg width="43" height="63" viewBox="0 0 43 63" fill="red">
  <g transform="translate(22 30)">
    <g>
      <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        attributeType="XML"
        type="scale"
        values="1; .8; 1"
        dur="2s"
        repeatCount="indefinite" />
      <path transform="translate(-22 -30)"
        d="M 2 2 L 21 5 L 41 2 L 36 29 L 41 60 L 21 55 L 2 60 L 7 29 Z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved pulsating effect with useAnimatedProps (reanimated version: 3.x). "width" and "height" were fixed.

Animating "viewBox" itself would not work: "minX", "minY", "vbWidth", "vbHeight" are needed. It has something to do with setNativeProps in React

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Animated, {
  useSharedValue,
  useAnimatedProps,
  withSpring,
} from "react-native-reanimated";
import Svg from "react-native-svg";

const AnimatedSvg = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Svg);

function AnimatedSvgBox({ minX, minY, vbWidth, vbHeight, children }) {
  const minXRa = useSharedValue(minX);
  const minYRa = useSharedValue(minY);
  const vbWidthRa = useSharedValue(vbWidth);
  const vbHeightRa = useSharedValue(vbHeight);

  useEffect(() => {
    minXRa.value = withSpring(minX);
    minYRa.value = withSpring(minY);
    vbWidthRa.value = withSpring(vbWidth);
    vbHeightRa.value = withSpring(vbHeight);
  }, [minX, minY, vbWidth, vbHeight]);

  const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => {
    return {
      viewBox: `${minX} ${minY} ${vbWidth} ${vbHeight}`,

      minX: minXRa.value,
      minY: minYRa.value,
      vbWidth: vbWidthRa.value,
      vbHeight: vbHeightRa.value,
    };
  });

  return (
    <AnimatedSvg width="100%" height="100%" animatedProps={animatedProps}>
      {children}
    </AnimatedSvg>
  );
}

export default AnimatedSvgBox;
```